# Disable/remove many infos when hoovering

Tags: visual-studio-code

As you can see there are many informations in the box. Lot of them are unuseful to me. Is there a way to reduce the infos. I need some infos but not all them and they are annoying

[image: Text]

Comment: what exactly from that screenshot do you want to be hidden and why?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust suggestion priority: You can also adjust the priority of suggestions in VS Code so that the most relevant suggestions appear first. To do this, go to Settings and search for "*editor.suggestSelection*". Change the value to "*recentlyUsed*" to prioritize suggestions you have recently used, or "first" to prioritize suggestions based on the current document.

Comment: In the above picture you see the first line enclosed in a box. That is the only info I need